# Retrieving Enterprise Project Types using Project Server Interface

Tags: web-services, project-server, psi, ms-project-server-2010

I am currently building an app to programatically create projects in Microsoft Project Server using the web services exposed through the Project Server Interface (PSI).

I am able to create a project with an Enterprise Project Type using the QueueCreateProject method, however, I need to specify the GUID of the EPT which I don't want to hard code into the code.

Is there another web service or way to get the GUID of a specific EPT found by its name?

Also, can the same be done for custom fields in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [PSI Filter parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453399%28v=office.12%29.aspx). Check out [this post](http://www.epmfaq.com/ssanderlin/project-server-2007/retrieve-the-guid-of-a-custom-field-using-its-name) for an example of retrieving the Guid of a custom field.

Really, I think the key is setting the filter criteria:

```
cfFilter.Criteria = new PSLibrary.Filter.FieldOperator(equal, nameColumn, customFieldName);
```

Where `nameColumn` is `cfDataSet.CustomFields.MD_PROP_NAMEColumn.ColumnName` and `customFieldName` is a value you pass in.

If you are like me, you want to do this for a lot of fields. I used a filter to query all the field names and `MD_PROP_UID`'s and then just put it in a hashtable so I don't have to keep making PSI calls.

<sub>Disclaimer: I use 2007 but I'm assuming it is mostly the same for custom fields (not for the EPT part which I didn't include).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12267251/1594383

In short: the methods are available from Workflow service.