# List available Enterprise Project Types using Project Server Interface

Tags: project-server

I want to query a Project Server 2010 installation for a list of available Enterprise Project Types (their names and GUIDs) using a webservice (PSI).

I can't find out how to do this anywhere.  I found a way using the [client-side object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163064%28v=office.15%29.aspx) but cannot find any examples using web services.  Has anyone ever done this?

I found one answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342983/retrieving-enterprise-project-types-using-project-server-interface) but it deals only with custom fields.

(The goal is to create/update a project using a Enterprise Project Type & its attached template.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 available methods inside of Workflow Service:

1. [Workflow.ReadAvailableEnterpriseProjectTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcworkflow.workflow.readavailableenterpriseprojecttypes_di_pj14mref.aspx) - list of EPTs available for the current user
2. [Workflow.ReadEnterpriseProjectTypeList Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcworkflow.workflow.readenterpriseprojecttypelist_di_pj14mref.aspx) - list of all known EPTs.

The only possible problem I see is a set of required permissions:

1. Manage Workflow
2. Change Workflow
3. + NewProject for the 1st method.